# Need to write a script if their is any pending changes from particular file or folder in git or bitbuket, the team city build should not trigger

Tags: shell, teamcity

How to handle the script where the pending changes from particular file. Build should abort and other this build should done periodically.

Answer (score 0):

If this file is not required for the build, you can use the Checkout rules inside the VCS settings of your Build Configuration.

Else, inside your VCS trigger in the trigger section, you specify folder to watch.

Comment: thank you for a response, here we don't have VCS Root for add the trigger rule.